# How to parameterize a query using INTERVAL

Tags: postgresql

The below query is syntactically correct, but it's not returning anything. I'm trying to find all data older than `?` months. I've been testing with 1 month, or even 1 day, but I don't get any data. Is there anything wrong with this query?

```
SELECT * FROM detail t
WHERE t.job_start_time < now() - (? * INTERVAL '1 MONTHS')
```

Comment: Your qery looks fine. Does it work if you pass a literal value instead of a parameter? You might want to check your data.

Comment: Where are you running this query? In other words how are passing in the argument to the parameter?

Comment: I’m running it as native Spring JPA query, in Java. But to test it I was using DBVisualizer.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using make_interval():

```
SELECT * 
FROM detail t
WHERE t.job_start_time < now() - make_interval(months => ?)
```